# Servlet - Force overwrite downloaded file

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2

How to change this code to **force overwrite** existing previously opened file saved on drive? It's part of servlet for opening pdf files on client side.

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;

try 
{
  input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
  output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int length;
  while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) 
  {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
} 
finally 
{
  close(output);
  close(input);
}
```

Each next copy of opened file has a new index, e.g. test.pdf, test(1).pdf and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** control that.

That is dependent on client's OS file system implementation

Comment: Thank you Jigar. It's little bit annoying, so I have to delete it manually time to time :(

Comment: *"You can't control that."*  Fortunately.  Never ceases to amaze me how many developers think they have the ability *or right* to force the end user to do (or not do) anything.  It may be *your* app., but your app. is a **guest** on *my* computer.

Comment: But it's the same for me. To have many different files or many indexed files :)

Comment: You're right Andrew, but in this case there is nothing like "my computer". It's an intranet application for corporate employees :)

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do it to configure the client browser to ask whether to overwrite or not, for example in Firefox it is:
[image]

To my knowledge asking to overwrite is the default behavior in Opera.

Comment: You can't force client to do this from Servlet :)

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I'm doing it exactly this way, problem is, that this affects all the other downloads. So I thought it could be done on servlet :)

Answer (score 0):

before going to write check whether the given file is exist or not?
using file api file.exists() if it exists, delete given file using file api file.delete() and continue with writing process

Comment: These would get invoked on server's JVM. and file would be on client's machine